# Correct way to run an ETL on a live production MongoDB database

Tags: mongodb, etl

We have the following environment:

- 3 servers + 3 replica set servers
- Each server has 3 shards
- Our main collection has around 40,000,000 documents that average at around 6kb
- Our shard key is hashed(_id) - _id being pure BsonID
- We peak daily at around 25,000 I/OPS and low point at around 10,000

We want to run an ETL that loads all of the documents on the main collection, do some in memory calculation (in our application tier) and then dumps it into an external DB.

We took the very poor and naive approach and simply loaded documents without a query using limit, skip and batchSize - which was a complete failure (severly hurt our service level - Even though we set the readPreference to secondary)

```
db.Collection.find().skip(i * 5000).limit(5000).readPref(secondary)
```

Where `i` is the current iteration we're going through, which runs on multiple threads to speed up the process.

I was wondering what would be the best approach to be able to load all of our documents without hurting the performance of our database.

The data can be a bit stale (a few seconds delay from the actual data on the primary is fine).

I've posted this question on DB admins but it doesn't seem to attract much answers so I'm posting it here as well. Sorry if it's against the forum rules.

Thanks!

Comment: They already use sharding, they want to just read and write elsewhere (ETL)

Comment: @JonathanMuller - that is correct

Comment: ever found a good solution yourself?

Comment: @JobVermeulen we took this approach and read from our secondaries not to impact the master servers